# Execute custom ArcGIS model with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, arcgis, arcobjects

I made a function which should execute a custom ArcGIS model.
I use VB 2010 with ArcGIS 10.2. The button which should execute this function is placed on a dockable window.

```
    Dim model As Geoprocessor = New Geoprocessor()
    model.AddToolbox("D:\Chris\Van Hall Larenstein\Ruimtelijke Informatie Technologie\RPS\RPS.tbx")

    Dim parameters As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IVariantArray = New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.VarArrayClass()
    model.Execute("RPS_TEST", parameters, Nothing)
```

There are no errors reported in VB 2010, but it doesn't work in ArcGIS. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
    Dim pToolHelper As IGPToolCommandHelper2 = New GPToolCommandHelper

    'Set the tool you want to invoke.
    Dim toolboxPath = "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Analysis Tools.tbx"
    pToolHelper.SetToolByName(toolboxPath, "Buffer")

    'Create the messages object to pass to the InvokeModal method.
    Dim msgs As IGPMessages
    msgs = New GPMessages

    'Invoke the tool.
    pToolHelper.InvokeModal(0, Nothing, True, msgs)
    My.ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = Nothing
```

Chris Driessen

Comment: The code looks fine. Model doesn't require any parameters?.

Comment: It does require parameters. But I don't want to declare the parameters in my code. They have to be declared in ArcGIS (reference shapefiles and fieldnames).

Answer (score 0):

If you want user define parameters than this is not the way to do it.
Your code immediately executes the model (without the parameters).

See [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001rz000000) link on how to open geoprocessing tool dialog.

Comment: This does not work for the Buffer tool, and does not work for the custom model.

VB does not give me errors, but in ArcGIS:  Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Comment: It works for all tools. You must be doing something wrong. Could you post your code?

Comment: See orignal question; I copied the code from Arcobjects. But maby this code isn't compatible in VB 10 and ArcGIS 10.2?

Comment: OK, this is strange. I rewrote your code in C# (I don't have VB.NET installed) and it works. The only differences are in the path of the toolbox and ArcGIS version. I have 32 bit ArcGIS 10.1 version. Yours is 64 bit judging by the path. It also works in 10.0.

Comment: Did you execute your code from with a button on a dockable window, or from a UI button in the ArcGIS toolbar?

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. Do you agree?
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001sw000000

Comment: I executed code from a button, but it doesn't matter from where it is executed. Regarding link you posted - it uses same code you already tried with your custom model.
What ArcGIS licence do you have? I think Buffer tool requires Advanced license. Maybe your custom model also uses tool(s) that require license level you don't have?

Comment: When I execute the model from the toolbox it works fine. So I don't think that is the problem.